# Using JsConstructor to deal with multiple constructors

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, gwt-jsinterop

I have a class with two constructors:

```
@JsType
public class Dog implements Animal {
    String name;

    public Dog() { 
        this.name = "Scooby Doo";
    }

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I run gwt compile [With GWT-dev 2.8]

```
[ERROR] Constructor 'Dog(String)' can be a JsConstructor only if all constructors in the class are delegating to it.
```

I have been trying to work through this error, with not much success. I am not sure how to delegate to the other constructor.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while that I've dealt with Java, but I'd guess that it wants all constructors to ultimately call a single implementation. Something like `public Dog(){ Dog("Scooby Doo") }`

Answer (score 2):

Alas, JavaScript can't handle multiple constructors! You get one and only one.

There are some things you can do to pretend to have more than one - you can check the incoming data, and assign sane defaults:

```
@JsConstructor
public Dog(@JsOptional String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        name = "Scooby Doo";
    }
    this.name = name;
}
```

You have to be careful of types here if your two constructors do not use the same types in the same position - judicious use of `instanceof` might work (just be aware that for JS objects you are using JS `instanceof`, not java!). Another option lets you be more flexible, but again, no overloaded methods - factory methods:

```
public static Dog withName(String name) {
    return new Dog(name);
}
public static Doc defaultImpl() {
    return new Dog();
}

@JsIgnore
public Dog() {/*...*/}
@JsIgnore
public Dog(String name) {/*...*/}
```

Another idea on the same theme would be to create a JsType builder. This is a bit less idiomatic for JS.

Finally, you could consider the dreaded "options object", where your one constructor takes a single Object with properties, or a `JsPropertyMap<Any>` holding all the possible values, then check nullness and types inside the giant constructor. I avoid this personally - this is one of the terrible things I'm hoping to avoid by writing Java in the first place.